# grub-customizer does not work

Tags: grub2

I have installed `grub-customizer`, I changed some settings and I use this command:

```bsh
sudo grub update
```

There are is no errors at all but there nothing changed in GRUB. What should I do?

Comment: Did you apply the changes in Grub Customizer?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had saved the changes on `grub-customizer`, ran `update-grub` and nothing. Until I realized I was updating GRUB from my usual OS and not the last one I installed (I had two Linux Mint 20.1 partitions, one with Mate and one with LXQt with low latency kernel).

So I followed the same process with `grub-customizer` on the last OS installed, which had the current GRUB menu, and all worked just fine, so keep that in mind too.

Comment: You saved my day! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When making changes to your GRUB config via `grub-customizer`, you need to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to apply those changes.